# MonoDevelop / GtkSharp - How to add item to the beginning of the list in TreeView?

Tags: c#, treeview, monodevelop, gtk#

Is possible to add item to GtkSharp TreeView on the top of list/tree?
This is possible in Windows Form for example by this way:
`listBox.Items.Insert(0, "anyItem");`

However I'm note able to find similar solution in GtkSharp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a ListStore or TreeStore object and assign it to the TreeView's Model property. Then you can insert or add items using the ListStore or TreeStore object.

Below is a simple example that uses a ListStore.

```
var listView = new TreeView ();
listView.HeadersVisible = false;

listStore = new ListStore (typeof(string));
listView.Model = listStore;

var cellView = new CellRendererText ();
var column = new TreeViewColumn ("Title", cellView);
column.AddAttribute (cellView, "text", 0);
listView.AppendColumn (column);
```

Then you can insert an item using:

```
 int position = 0;
 listStore.InsertWithValues (position, "MyItem");
```

Comment: Miracle. It works, thank you very much,  but problem is, that vertical scrollbar moves down together with first items and new incomig items above aren't to see. Do you know, how to fix this problem, please? I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Additional info to this - In WindowsForm this is possible by using  `listBox.SelectedIndex = 0` and then is each new item selected and also visible.      Is something similar possible in  Mono too?

Comment: The TreeView has a ScrollToCell method you can use to ensure a particular row is visible.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try this.